# What amount of odometry drift would be considered having an accurate base?

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working on some projects and it occurred to me that I've never seen any documents where people specify their robot base odometry drift to benchmark what a typical amount of drift would be and what's the point where I can say I have "good" odometry.

For instance, when I move my base in a 20 meter perimeter square, in forward direction I have about 20cm drift (1%) and in the lateral direction, I have about 50cm (2.5%) drift on a differential drive base.

Can anyone share here their specification or documentation of others?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/302121/what-amount-of-odometry-drift-would-be-considered-having-an-accurate-base?/) by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8272 on 2018-08-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Arrr, I'd think ye should be lookin fer' some researrrch, mat'ee. Calibration papers be adverrrtisin' all manner o' statistics.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2018-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0